# how to let an app access android system recovery menu

Tags: android, performance, reset, data-recovery

please is the a way to let an app access the bootloader menu of android? As in , when a person attempts to perform a hard reset, can an app or messagebox pop up to deny the person?

Answer (score 0):

> please is the a way to let an app access the bootloader menu of android?

Perhaps on rooted devices you can modify the behavior of that menu, somehow. Otherwise, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons, beyond the technical ones.

> when a person attempts to perform a hard reset, can an app or messagebox pop up to deny the person?

I sure hope not, again for obvious security reasons. Malware authors would *love* to prevent people from resetting their device to remove the malware.

Comment: I'm hoping to find a way to prevent people from performing a hard reset on stolen phones since that seems to be what gives thieves the confidence to keep on stealing phones

Comment: @LorenzoChristaddictImpetioni: That is the responsibility of device manufacturers and custom ROM developers.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare